# google cardboard scene not rendering properly with unity 5 when depoly to android mobile

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rendering, google-cardboard

I am trying a sample scene with google cardboard using unity 5. But when i deploy to android mobile the screen just becomes very noisy. Cant see anything. Please let me know if you have encountered this problem and how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share any of your code? Your description of your problem seems vague.

Comment: What is "noisy", exactly?

Comment: @Max ,@Wai Here is a screen shot of the output. The scene contains only a plane and a couple of cubes. ScreenShot link: http://s10.postimg.org/mjx9kuah5/device_2015_05_12_170458.jpg

Comment: @MaxYankov :please have a look at the screen shot from previous comment

Comment: @Albin Does the demo scene from the unity plugin work for you?

Comment: @staker yes the sample scene worked for me.

Comment: Two things you can try: 
i. In Unity Editor, Under Game Object Hierarchy, go to CardboardMain>Head>MainCamera, turn off Direct Render property under Stereo Controller script.
ii. Turn on Development Build under Build Settings.

You can refer to this Release Note: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/release-notes.